# Erro de sintaxe próximo a 'limit'

Tags: sql-server, query

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
select coluna1, coluna2, coluna3 from tabela
where coluna2 > 0 
order by coluna3 desc
limit 10
```

E quando executo aparece o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>  Incorrect syntax near 'limit'-
> ```
>
> <sub>[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSwOe.png)</sub>

Comment: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna2 >= '0' ORDER BY coluna3 DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Não seria assim?

Comment: Testei dessa forma e continuou dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Poste o código todo, por favor.

Comment: Sua Query parece correta, você realmente está usando o mysql? não é um mssql ou sql server?

Comment: Acho que você está usando outro banco de dados que não seja o MySql. Se for o SQL Server é `top`.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema usando a solução do Diego Souza. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MySQL** - Usando o `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT
    coluna1,
    coluna2,
    coluna3
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    coluna2 > 0
ORDER BY
    coluna3 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**SQL Server** - Usando `TOP`.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    coluna1,
    coluna2,
    coluna3
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    coluna2 > 0
ORDER BY
    coluna3 DESC
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema usando o SELECT TOP 10. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Perfeito @LorennaChristna basta aceitar a resposta dele como correta. Lado esquerdo, abaixo dos votos. :)

Comment: Eu estava mesmo procurando aonde se fazia isso hahahaha! Super obrigada! :)